# Import a specific Javascript library in to Angular 4 (if library doesn't export a variable)

Tags: json, angular, typescript, typescript-typings

I am trying to show a diff for two JSON objects in Angular 4 view, I am using this library ([angular-object-diff](https://github.com/hipster-labs/angular-object-diff)) originally built for AngularJS.


Demo of that library: [Link](http://hipster-labs.github.io/angular-object-diff/)
I tried to import this JS library the following way:

 JS file I am trying to import: [angular-object-diff.js](https://github.com/hipster-labs/angular-object-diff/blob/master/dist/angular-object-diff.js), doesnt have a exported variable

In my typings.d.ts ( I added the following):

```
declare var ObjectDiff: any;
```

In my angular-cli.json, I added

```
"scripts": [
    "../node_modules/angular-object-diff/dist/angular-object-diff.js"
  ],
```

In my component file:

```
const json1 = {
  name: 'John'
};
const json2 = {
  name: 'Johnny'
};
const diff = ObjectDiff.diffOwnProperties(json1, json2);
this.jsonViewData = ObjectDiff.toJsonDiffView(diff);
```

In my view:

```
<pre ng-bind-html="jsonViewData"></pre>
<pre> {{jsonViewData}}</pre>
```

**Nothing seems to be working, I get the error that "ObjectDiff" is not defined in the console"**

Can someone please let me know if I am doing in thing wrong  ?
Suggestions for displaying the JSON diff are also welcomed :)

** Thank you

Comment: I don't think you can use that library without also using something to make the angularjs library compatible with angular4.

Comment: Yes, got it. Thank you @toskv.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The library doesn't export anything. It uses IIFE to not pollute global scope with local variables. It's impossible to reach local variables from the outside, this makes Module pattern so effective (and annoying).

The library uses AngularJS `angular` global and expects that it will exist. This creates a problem, because Angular 4 application should mock `angular` global in this case. Moreover, the code itself relies on AngularJS-specific units (`$sce` service).

The library should be forked and modified to suit the expectations. The mentions of `angular` should be removed. Considering that script will be executed in module scope, IIFE should be removed and appropriate exports should be added.

Comment: Makes sense, Thank you very much @estus for the detailed explanation.

Comment: You're welcome. Considering that you'll want to do the same thing in Angular 4, you will likely want to replace $sce with similar https://angular.io/api/platform-browser/DomSanitizer `bypassSecurityTrustHtml`.